# C++ read binary file and convert to hex

Tags: c++, hex, binary-data

I'm having some problems reading a binary file and converting it's bytes to hex representation.

What I've tried so far:

```
ifstream::pos_type size;
char * memblock;

ifstream file (toread, ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
  if (file.is_open())
  {
    size = file.tellg();
    memblock = new char [size];
    file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    file.read (memblock, size);
    file.close();

    cout << "the complete file content is in memory" << endl;

std::string tohexed = ToHex(memblock, true);


    std::cout << tohexed << std::endl;

   }
```

Converting to hex:

```
string ToHex(const string& s, bool upper_case)
{
    ostringstream ret;

    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
        ret << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (upper_case ? std::uppercase : std::nouppercase) << (int)s[i];

    return ret.str();
}
```

Result: `53514C69746520666F726D61742033`.

When I open the original file with a hex editor, this is what it shows:

```
53 51 4C 69 74 65 20 66 6F 72 6D 61 74 20 33 00
04 00 01 01 00 40 20 20 00 00 05 A3 00 00 00 47
00 00 00 2E 00 00 00 3B 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 A3
00 2D E2 1E 0D 03 FC 00 06 01 80 00 03 6C 03 D3
```

Is there a way to get the same desired output using C++?

**Working solution** (by Rob):

```
...

std::string tohexed = ToHex(std::string(memblock, size), true);

...
string ToHex(const string& s, bool upper_case)
{
    ostringstream ret;

    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    {
        int z = s[i]&0xff;
        ret << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (upper_case ? std::uppercase : std::nouppercase) << z;
    }

    return ret.str();
}
```

Comment: "memblock contains only first 15 bytes, stopping at the null byte (16th)" What makes you say that? I don't see where you are printing out the contents of `memblock`. I suspect that `memblock` contains the entire file, but that the code you aren't showing us misinterprets its contents. Please reduce your program to the smallest complete program that demonstrates the error, and post that program in the question. http://sscce.org

Comment: @Rob okay shall i repost the first 15 bytes for you to be more clear?

Comment: Assuming that this is a homework or a learning assignment of some sort, here's a couple of hints: (1) you are missing a `while` loop, (2) calling `tellg()` on a stream that you have just opened is premature.

Comment: @develroot - No, please just tell us how you concluded that it only contained the first fifteen bytes.

Comment: that's what it shows when I run the program.

Comment: Have you checked that the value of `size` isn't 15 bytes, just by pure coincidence being the count before the first null byte? `ifstream` in binary mode certainly isn't supposed to do anything with null bytes...

Comment: @develroot - "that's what it shows when I run the program". What program? Please post a complete minimal program that demonstrates the error, so that we can help you find the error. http://sscce.org

Comment: @sscce.org what should I post? the includes? the return 0; or what? THIS IS THE WHOLE PROGRAM

Comment: @develroot - That is by no means the entire program, but it was sufficient to find the error. *Please* read http://sscce.org to understand why I asked you for a complete program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
char *memblock;
… 
std::string tohexed = ToHex(memblock, true);
…

string ToHex(const string& s, bool upper_case)
```

There's your problem, right there. The constructor `std::string::string(const char*)` interprets its input as a nul-terminated string. So, only the characters leading up to `'\0'` are even passed to `ToHex`.  Try one of these instead:

```
std::string tohexed = ToHex(std::string(memblock, memblock+size), true);
std::string tohexed = ToHex(std::string(memblock, size), true);
```

Comment: okay...that worked for the hex conversion...but i still have a problem: the result isn't exactly the same. `47` is now `00`, or `2D` is now `05`..and so are all the non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @develroot - if it helps, you have a sign-extension bug in your `ToHex` routine. Try `(s[i]&0xff)` instead of `(int)s[i]`.

Comment: This is amazing! :)