# How to convert image file *.jpg to hex code in C?

Tags: c, image, hex, jpeg

I'm trying to read a JPG image file  and convert it to string of hex code (not hex of pixel) in C.

Something like:

`FFD8FFE000114A464946000102030405060708090AFFDB00...`.

I tried many way but not working. Someone has any idea?

My code which I tried with stb libraries: https://codeload.github.com/nothings/stb/zip/master

```
// USAGE: gcc -std=c99 image.c -o image -lm
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

const size_t NUM_PIXELS_TO_PRINT = 10U;

int main(void) {
    int width, height, comp;
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load("r3.jpg", &width, &height, &comp, 0);
    if (data) {
        printf("width = %d, height = %d, comp = %d (channels)\n", width, height, comp);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_PIXELS_TO_PRINT * comp; i++) {
            printf("%02x%s", data[i], ((i + 1) % comp) ? "" : "\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error I got when try with John Smith:

```
ImageProcess.c: In function ‘main’:
ImageProcess.c:14:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘bzero’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     bzero(data, fsize + 1);
     ^
ImageProcess.c:18:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘hexlifyn’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     char* yourDataStr = hexlifyn((char*)data, (uint)fsize);
     ^
ImageProcess.c:18:48: error: ‘uint’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     char* yourDataStr = hexlifyn((char*)data, (uint)fsize);
                                                ^
ImageProcess.c:18:48: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
ImageProcess.c:18:53: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘fsize’
     char* yourDataStr = hexlifyn((char*)data, (uint)fsize);
                                                     ^
ImageProcess.c: At top level:
ImageProcess.c:21:28: error: unknown type name ‘uint’
 char *hexlifyn(char *bstr, uint str_len) {
                            ^
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you actually want the hex string to represent? Should it just be a binary dump of the file (i.e. represent "the bytes on the harddrive")?

Comment: Actually, I don't know much about what hex can be represented on image. But the bytes on the hardware seem like quite compatible with my case.

Comment: I tried with stb libraries but it only get hex of each pixel.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. If you don't want hex of each pixel, do you mean, you do not want to decompress the JPG file? Do you just want to read the file and write content (compressed JPG) as hex string?

Comment: Yes, Gerhardh. I want to write content as hex string.

Comment: _"I tried with stb libraries but it only get hex of each pixel"_: show us what you have tried, then me might be able to tell you what you id wrong. [Edit] your question and clarify. Read this: [ask]

Comment: Yes, you have been updated my question.

Comment: It's still unclear what you want. What makes you think your code is not working? Does your code compile? Does it run? Does it crash? Does it display something else than what you expect? Please [edit] and clarify. "Not working" is not a problem description.

Comment: No, my code is working, but I get hex of pixel.

Comment: @ToanVnET so you basically want to read the jpg file byte per byte and display the hexadecimal representation to each of the bytes? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, Jabberwocky.

Comment: You don't need STB_image at all, because you aren't trying to understand or interpret or process the image in any way at all... all you are doing is a hex dump, same as you'd get if you ran `xxd -p IMAGE.JPG` and `xxd` knows nothing about JPEG/PNG or anything else. You just need to open your file in binary and read each byte and display it in hex.

Comment: How can I reach that ? It's sound great.

Comment: Thank you so much Mark Setchell. I solved my issue. Same way as you said.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to get the contents of a file as hex string than that should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() { 
    char* file_name = "/path/to/any.png";
    FILE *f = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    if (f==NULL) return;
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t fsize = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    void*data = malloc(fsize + 1);
    bzero(data, fsize + 1);
    fread(data, 1, fsize, f);
    fclose(f);

    char* yourDataStr = hexlifyn((char*)data, (uint)fsize);
}

char *hexlifyn(char *bstr, uint str_len) {
    char *hstr=malloc((str_len*2)+1);
    bzero(hstr,(str_len*2)+1);
    char *phstr=hstr;
    for(int i=0; i<str_len;i++) {
        *phstr++ =v2a((bstr[i]>>4)&0x0F);
        *phstr++ =v2a((bstr[i])&0x0F);
    }
    *phstr++ ='\0';
    return hstr;
}

char v2a(int c) {
    const char hex[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    return hex[c];
}
```

Comment: No. It's not working. A lot of warning and error. Did I missing something when I compiled it:

`gcc -std=c99 ImageDumpHex.c -o image`

Comment: It seems you don‘t have much knowledge of C in many regards, so I would advice you to read online about the basics at least. If you absolutely need to fix it now, for the uint error, it’s defined here `#include <stdint.h>`, for the warnings, you need to write a header for the functions of course or move them above the caller (main)

Comment: Thank you, I solved my issues. I just open file image and read each byte of image and display it.

Comment: @JohnSmith how to get it back to its original format?

Answer (score 1):

From your comment I understand that you want to retrieve the binary contents of a file (i.e. a JPG image) as a hexadecimal string.

What you're looking for is something called "**hex dump**". There are various libraries and snippets available that allow doing this with C.

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621893/c-read-binary-file-and-convert-to-hex) addresses exactly this issue.

Comment: I work in C. I not sure these C++ function is working with C.

Comment: The crucial part of this answer is the fact that you're looking for doing a "hex dump". That information should open you a door of a multitude of ready-to-go solutions from small copy-paste code snippets up to fully fledged library integrated solutions. To point you to something specific we'd need to know more about your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you image file output as a continuous hex string in your terminal as well as a .txt file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
string myText;
int main()
{
  system("xxd -p image.jpg > image.txt | tr -d '\n'");
  

ifstream MyReadFile("./image.txt");

while (getline (MyReadFile, myText)) {
  // Output the text from the file
  cout << myText;
}


MyReadFile.close(); 
  return 0;
}
```